# python3 bdist_egg cannot install in python2?

Tags: python, setuptools, egg

My `setup.py` is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='demo',
      version='0.0.1',
      packages=["demo"],
      package_dir={'demo':'demo'},
      install_requires=["requests"],
)
```

then I dist it:

```
source activate py3
python setup.py bdist_eg
```

I run it in `python 3.6`, `setuptools==36.2.7`, get egg file like this: `dist/demo-0.0.1-py3.6.egg`. I install this egg file without any errors in python3.

But if I want to install this egg file in `python 2.7`, I run this:

```
source activate py2
easy_install dist/demo-0.0.1-py3.6.egg
```

I got error like this:

```
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('demo==0.0.1')
```

Comment: Which version of seruptools are you using for Python 2.7?

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE `setuptools==36.2.7` in python2.7. I use [`anaconda`](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

Comment: I suggest you to use **pip** instead of **easy_install**. More modern and can handle the "wheel" format.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE But how to use `pip` install local egg file? And also, `easy_install` is provided by `setuptools` itself, it should works

Comment: if you have a recent version of **pip** you can install "egg" files. Or, upgrade it: `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Answer (score 1):

The best practices nowadays is to use the [wheel](http://pythonwheels.com) format (instead of egg) and install with pip.

In your virtualenv:

```
pip install wheel
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

In your `dist` directory you'll a .whl file.

Then in py2 virtualenv you can do:

```
pip install your-lib-xyz.whl
```